# sync google chrome and internet explorer bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, sync, google-bookmarks, xmarks

Can any one tell me of a good way to sync Google chrome bookmarks to Internet Explorer favorites?
I Have already tried Xmarks, however to use this means turning off Google bookmark sync and if I do that i loos the bookmarks on Google chrome on my Iphone. So I am looking for something similar that will not make me turn off Google chromes native bookmark sync feature.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no problem using Google Chrome and using its syncing options with the Xmarks extension enable.  Xmarks really is about it.

Comment: Il keep trying, but whenever It would try to sync it would show as skipping bookmarks and I read it can be from chrome sync feature interfering